# Use Doxygen to document a function that is sent to a MACRO C++

Tags: c++, macros, doxygen

Recently we added some code to label deprecated code at compile time using MACROS.  Now Doxygen does not document the deprecated functions properly.

```
    #if defined(__GNUC__)
    #define DEPRECATED(func) func __attribute__((deprecated)) /**< mark a function as deprecated in gcc. */ 

    #elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define DEPRECATED(func) __declspec(deprecated) func /**< mark a function as deprecated in msvc. */
    #endif
```

Note this is a simplified version of the macros for this post the actual macros do compiler version checks etc.

Later the macros are used around a function to let the compiler know that the function has been deprecated so a compiler warning will be issued.

```
    /**
     * myMethod() is deprecated.
     */
    DEPRECATED(
        /**
         * @deprecated
         * Description of deprecated function
         * 
         * @param var this is a parameter
         *
         * @return this is returned 
         */
        int myMethod(int var)
    );
```

The problem is that Doxygen wants to show the documentation for DEPRECATED not for myMethod(int var).

Does anyone know how to get Doxygen to document myMethod and not the macro DEPRECATED?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should tell doxygen that it has to remove the `DEPRECATED` macro. You can do this using the following preprocessor options in the configuration file:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = "DEPRECATED(x)=x"
```

You can debug the result of preprocessing by running doxygen with the `-d Preprocessor` option. When this option is present, Doxygen will dump the input file to the output after preprocessing has been performed.

For more info see http://www.doxygen.org/preprocessing.html

Comment: I actually found the same solution and was about to post it.  Just a note for PREDEFINED the value should be "DEPRECATED(x)=x" with out the quotes it did not give correct results.  The link given in your solution was how I found the solution as well.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [@fn tag](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfn) to explicitly tell what the block is referring to. Not as convenient as the implicit connection, but safer.

Comment: That was the first thing that I tried.  If that had worked I would not have posted here.  The problem with using the @fn tag is that Doxygen needs to see the function.

Comment: The @fn tag is so you can separate the documentation from the function.  Its not so you can document a function that Doxygen does not think exist.  I have tried to change the MACRO_EXPANSION options so that Doxygen would process the  DEPRICATED macro before trying to apply the documentation.  I think that was the right direction but I could not get it to work.